how to remove classes / objectProperty / Data Property from TTL File via OWL Library
In My TTL file, i need to remove the below objectProperty named hasPrice.

###  http://internal.lowes.com/ontologies/2024/#objectprop/hasPrice
<http://internal.lowes.com/ontologies/2024/#objectprop/hasPrice> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

I tried to remove it with axoim below, but it is not reflecting in the TTL File.
Same approach applied for class and data property as well.
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = new OWLDataFactoryImpl();
OWLOntologyID targetOntology = new OWLOntologyID(IRI.create(urn));

OWLEntity entity = dataFactory.getOWLEntity(EntityType.OBJECT_PROPERTY, IRI.create(iri));
RemoveAxiomData removeAxiomData = new RemoveAxiomData(dataFactory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(entity));
owlOntologyChangeRecords.add(new OWLOntologyChangeRecord(targetOntology, removeAxiomData));

OWLObjectProperty subProperty = new OWLObjectPropertyImpl(IRI.create(iri));
OWLObjectProperty superProperty = new OWLObjectPropertyImpl(IRI.create(parentIri));
OWLObjectPropertyAxiom owlObjectPropertyAxiom = new OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiomImpl(subProperty, superProperty, new ArrayList<>());
RemoveAxiomData removeAxiomDataSubProperty = new RemoveAxiomData(owlObjectPropertyAxiom);
owlOntologyChangeRecords.add(new OWLOntologyChangeRecord(targetOntology, removeAxiomDataSubProperty));

final OWLLiteral labellingLiteral= dataFactory.getOWLLiteral(name);

IRI annotationPropertyIri = RDFS_LABEL.getIRI();
OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom ax = dataFactory.getOWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom(
        dataFactory.getOWLAnnotationProperty(annotationPropertyIri), entity.getIRI(), labellingLiteral);
RemoveAxiomData removeAxiomDataAnnotation = new RemoveAxiomData(ax);
owlOntologyChangeRecords.add(new OWLOntologyChangeRecord(targetOntology, removeAxiomDataAnnotation));


Your code doesn't show the ontology being saved after the changes are applied. You need to save the ontology for changes to be persisted
